# Function doesn't return true or false ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

When I call my permissionCheck it doesn't return true or false.
The permissions useState is full.

This is the part of my code:

```
const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState({});

const permissionCheck = (permission) =>
    {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
        {
            if (permissions[i].name === permission)
            {
                return false;
            } else if (permissions[i].name !== permission) return true;
        }
    }


// the outcome will be set on the hidden component. So if the outcome is true it will be hidden and if it is false it will be shown
hidden={permissionCheck('TEST')}
```

Comment: Your `permissions` isn't an array, it's an object, `permissions.length` is undefined, the loop won't even run once. Therefore no return statement will be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to iterate through an object which does not work

Change permissions from object

```
const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState({});
```

To array:

```
const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState([]);
```

And amend your function as follows:

```
const permissionCheck = (permission) =>
{
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
    {
        if (permissions[i].name === permission)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not returning. If both conditions are not met.

Change

```
const permissionCheck = (permission) =>
    {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
        {
            if (permissions[i].name === permission)
            {
                return false;
            } else if (permissions[i].name !== permission) return true;
        } 
      //  There is no default return, so you are not getting any returned value
    }
```

to

```
const permissionCheck = (permission) =>
    {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
        {
            if (permissions[i].name === permission)
                return false;
        }
        return true; //  so now one return is assured.
    }
```